# $G$ is a connected and bipartite graph and $G$ is regular of grade $k>1$ prove $G$ is biconnected

Tags: graph-theory

I need some help with this problem, I try to prove that all vertices of $G$ is in a cycle by I can't prove it. Can you help me?

> Let $G$ be a connected and bipartite graph and $G$ is regular of grade $k>1$, prove that $G$ is a biconnected graph.